# What is the output for the following lines of code? var x = null; var z = "sp"; if (x==true){ z+=1; } console.log(z); *

Tags: javascript

What is the output for the following lines of code?
var x = null; var z = "sp"; if (x==true){ z+=1; } console.log(z);
*

Comment: your variable **x** is **null** so the if statement will never run. Your output will be "sp" by the way, why should you ask such here?

Answer (score 0):

`Null` is a falsy value in Javascript. So, the condition will not turn true. The output you will get will definitely be "sp".

```js
var x = null;
var z = "sp";
if (x==true){
  z+=1; 
}
console.log(z);
```

0, 0n, null, undefined, false, NaN, and the empty string "" are falsy values in JS.
If you try to run the above code with any of the falsy values, your condition will evalute to false and the code between the parenthesis will never run.

```js
var x;
var z;

x = null;
z = "sp";
if (x==true){
  z+=1; 
}
console.log(z);

x = 0;
z = "sp";
if (x==true){
  z+=1; 
}
console.log(z);

x = "";
z = "sp";
if (x==true){
  z+=1; 
}
console.log(z);

x = undefined;
z = "sp";
if (x==true){
  z+=1; 
}
console.log(z);

x = false;
z = "sp";
if (x==true){
  z+=1; 
}
console.log(z);

x = NaN;
z = "sp";
if (x==true){
  z+=1; 
}
console.log(z);
```